# How to extract altitude above sea level given latitude and longitude?

Tags: r, google-maps, latitude-longitude, google-latitude, google-elevation-api

I am trying to extract altitude data for a given set of lats and longs in my data. I tried to look up some older answers (from 9-10 years ago)..but many of the methods are obsolete or the functions don't work. Any fresh suggestions?

```
lat <- c(45.08323,40.08323)
long <- c(-82.46797,-81.46797)
df <- data.frame(lat, long)
```

I have tried the following suggestions:

1. [Using the geonames package, and get the value from the srtm3 digital elevation model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8975851/6820344)

I run into errors that say: `Error in url(url, open = "r") :    cannot open the connection to 'http://api.geonames.org/srtm3JSON?lat=NA&lng=NA&`

2. I tried using the [googleway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41773871/6820344) and [elevatr pacakages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elevatr/index.html) as suggested in the linked answers

The elevatr package would not download for the latest R > 4.0 version.

```
I get an error that says   Configuration failed because libudunits2.so was not found. Try installing:
    * deb: libudunits2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, ...)
    * rpm: udunits2-devel (Fedora, EPEL, ...)
    * brew: udunits (OSX)
  If udunits2 is already installed in a non-standard location, use:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib'
  if the library was not found, and/or:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'
  if the header was not found, replacing paths with appropriate values.
  You can alternatively set UDUNITS2_INCLUDE and UDUNITS2_LIBS manually.
```

When I try installing the required package:

> "package ‘libudunits2’ is not available for this version of R"

###EDIT: What worked?

```
library(geonames)
readLines(url("http://api.geonames.org/",open="r"))
options(geonamesUsername= "MyUsername") #Note you have to create a username one the website AND enable webservices on your geonames user account at https://www.geonames.org/manageaccount. 

GNsrtm3(54.481084,-3.220625)
```

Comment: how about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973695/conversion-for-latitude-longitude-to-altitude-in-r or https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elevatr/vignettes/introduction_to_elevatr.html

Comment: @user20650 Neither worked. For the first one, it kept saying error in connection and the second one the package failed to load in the latest R version

Comment: okay. It would probably be helpful if you added all the things you have tried and that have not worked to your question  to save wasting your time with suggestions

Comment: Thanks.The geonames requires a username which you then pass in the options -- see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geonames/index.html. However, I just signed up and ot didn't accept it straight away ... maybe it takes a while. But using `"demo"` username seemed to work (for now); `library(geonames) ; options(geonamesUsername="demo") ; GNsrtm3(54.481084,-3.220625)`. Not tried any of the others

Comment: the second errors are because you need system libraries . so try `apt install  libudunits2-dev` (from `sudo`) -- or which ever is relevant -- and then try to reinstall

Comment: `libudunits2` is a **system** package, not an R package. The installation instructions are given in the error message for Linux (`deb`, `rpm`) or MacOS (`brew`)

Comment: for geonames; after signing up this seems relevant https://github.com/ropensci/geonames/issues/20

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the clarification. I think then it maybe the larger problem I seem to dealing with R now-a-days with R on the Mac System. I have come to nearly tears of frustration trying to figure out the "tcl-tk"/ Quartz update for later R version on Mac with little success. I can't use so many more package like BiodiversityR adonis etc..because of this. So trying all other routes (sigh...)

Comment: @user20650 I created a username on web and it still says HTTP status was '401 Unauthorized' .For "demo" it says.. `the daily limit of 20000 credits for demo has been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use the demo account for your application.` maybe I need to wait out

Comment: @Biotechgeek; from the github link above; if you go to the link https://www.geonames.org/manageaccount and under the login and password oyu will see "**Free Web Services
the account is not yet enabled to use the free web services. Click here to enable.**". So click to enable and then it will accept your username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This manages to get the second point, but not the first.

```
library(elevatr)
library(rgdal)
lat <- c(45.08323,40.08323)
long <- c(-82.46797,-81.46797)
df <- data.frame(long, lat)
get_elev_point(df, prj="EPSG:4326")
# Note: Elevation units are in &units=Meters 
# Note:. The coordinate reference system is:
#  GEOGCRS["WGS 84 (with axis order normalized for visualization)",
#     DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
#         ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
#             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
#     PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
#         ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
#     CS[ellipsoidal,2],
#         AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
#             ORDER[1],
#             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
#                 ID["EPSG",9122]]],
#         AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
#             ORDER[2],
#             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
#                 ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
#             coordinates elevation elev_units
# 1 (-82.46797, 45.08323)        NA     meters
# 2 (-81.46797, 40.08323)    271.82     meters
```

Comment: using `GNsrtm3`  the results are 175 & 277

Answer (score 1):

Need to create a username and enable webservice on https://www.geonames.org/manageaccount

```
    library(geonames)
    readLines(url("http://api.geonames.org/",open="r"))
    options(geonamesUsername= "MyUsername") #Note you have to create a username one the website AND enable webservices on your geonames user account at https://www.geonames.org/manageaccount. 
    
    GNsrtm3(54.481084,-3.220625)
```